# Rheostat at 0% interaction with Ohm's law

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

While working on an assignment, I recently came across something that I can't understand. I have a rheostat and an ammeter connected in line. When the rheostat gets the value $0$ I get a reading on the ammeter of  $10$ kA. Is there a way to "fix" this ? Keep in mind I am very new to electricity as we weren't taught that in primary school :).

[image]

Comment: Is this a real circuit or a computer simulation?

Comment: If $R=0$ and $V=10$ $ Volts the current should be infinite!

Comment: @PhilipWood Its a simulation on multisim.

Comment: @mikestone I mean the ammeter has a tiny resistance itself. 1 x 10 ^(-9) Ω.

Comment: So this is just what you'd expect. In a real version of the circuit you'd probably destroy the ammeter and possibly melt the wires by putting the rheostat to zero resistance. The circuit should have a fixed resistor in series so that this can't happen.